Attach DB Browser for SQLite Read-Only
Intro
I am attaching to SQLite databases using DB Browser for SQLite. These databases hold archive data that I want to keep untouched. From there I want to copy data for reporting purposes.

(the archived DBs are hosted in OneDrive - so the traditional READONLY attribute seems to be moot)
(this is part of a rag-tag "design" that isn't going to end users, but for sporadic internal Frankestein sporadic tooling)

BUT
I want to do this in a non-destructive way and be sure other users that use my SQL don't attach to the archived databases in a way that changes the archives.
QUESTION(s)

Is there a way of ATTACH'ing to an SQLite .db file from another (reporting) DB in a READ-ONLY way?
Can I make a synchronized OneDrive directory on a user's PC a read-only folder?
(which may be a problem for SQLite clients attaching to the DBs in the cloud folder due to the requirement to create journal files)

